# Find the index of a dict within a list, by matching the dict's value

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts:

```
list = [{'id':'1234','name':'Jason'},
        {'id':'2345','name':'Tom'},
        {'id':'3456','name':'Art'}]
```

How can I efficiently find the index position [0],[1], or [2] by matching on name = 'Tom'?

If this were a one-dimensional list I could do list.index() but I'm not sure how to proceed by searching the values of the dicts within the list.

Comment: "list" is the list constructor, you better choose another name for a list (even in a example). And what should be the response if no element is found? raise an exception? return None?

Comment: If you're going to need this a lot, use a more appropriate data structure (perhaps `{ 'Jason': {'id': '1234'}, 'Tom': {'id': '1245'}, ...}`?)

Comment: @delnan Because that's a recipe for disaster! If anything, it should be `{'1234': {'name': 'Jason'}, ...}`. Not that that would help this use-case.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

```
lst = [{'id':'1234','name':'Jason'}, {'id':'2345','name':'Tom'}, {'id':'3456','name':'Art'}]

tom_index = next((index for (index, d) in enumerate(lst) if d["name"] == "Tom"), None)
# 1
```

If you need to fetch repeatedly from name, you should index them by name (using a dictionary), this way *get* operations would be O(1) time. An idea:

```
def build_dict(seq, key):
    return dict((d[key], dict(d, index=index)) for (index, d) in enumerate(seq))

people_by_name = build_dict(lst, key="name")
tom_info = people_by_name.get("Tom")
# {'index': 1, 'id': '2345', 'name': 'Tom'}
```

Comment: IMHO this is not as readable or Pythonic is @Emile's answer. Because the intention is not really to create a generator (and using `next()` for this seems weird to me), the aim is just to get the index. Also, this raises StopIteration, whereas the Python `lst.index()` method raises ValueError.

Comment: @benhoyt: I don't like the StopIteration exception either, but while you can change next()'s default value, the exception it raises is fixed. The pythonicity is somewhat subjective so I won't dispute it, probably a for-loop is more pythonic. On the other hand, some people aliases next() for first(), and that definitely sounds better: first(index for (index, d) in ...).

Comment: `first()` does sound better. You could always try/except the StopIteration and raise ValueError so the caller has consistency. Alternatively set `next()`'s default to -1.

Comment: This is one of the things that python got wrong.  Not allowing a optional comparator for the index function.  Code like this is a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: `next(index for (index, d) in enumerate(lst) if d["name"] == "Tom", None)` will return `None` instead of raising an exception if nothing is found.

Comment: @gdw2: yes, we discussed it with benhoyt on earlier comments.

Comment: @gdw2: I get `SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument` when doing that.

Comment: @avoliva add a parenthesis around next like follows `next((index for (index, d) in enumerate(lst) if d["name"] == "Tom"), None)`

Comment: I need first to know what is lst?

Comment: I would change the `d["name"]` part to `d.get("name")`, since in the first case I was getting a `KeyError`

Answer (score 73):

A simple readable version is

```
def find(lst, key, value):
    for i, dic in enumerate(lst):
        if dic[key] == value:
            return i
    return -1
```

Comment: This seems the most readable and Pythonic. It also mimics the behaviour of `str.find()` nicely. You could also call it `index()` and raise a `ValueError` instead of returning -1 if that was preferable.

Comment: Agreed - by returning -1 when no match is found, you'll always get the last dict in the list, which is probably not what you want. Better to return None and check for exsistence of a match in the calling code.

Answer (score 14):

It won't be efficient, as you need to walk the list checking every item in it (O(n)). If you want efficiency, you can use **dict of dicts**. 
On the question, here's one possible way to find it (though, if you want to stick to this data structure, it's actually more efficient to **use a generator** as Brent Newey has written in the comments; see also tokland's answer):

```
>>> L = [{'id':'1234','name':'Jason'},
...         {'id':'2345','name':'Tom'},
...         {'id':'3456','name':'Art'}]
>>> [i for i,_ in enumerate(L) if _['name'] == 'Tom'][0]
1
```

Comment: You can gain the efficiency you desire by using a generator. See tokland's answer.

Comment: @Brent Newey: The generator does not change the fact, that you have to traverse the entire list, making the search O(n) as aeter claims... Depending on how long that list is, the difference between using a generator vs using a for loop or whatever might be neglible, wheras the difference between using a dict vs. using a list might not

Comment: @Brent: You are right, but can it beat a O(1) lookup in a dictionary, moreover if the searched item is at the end of the list?

Comment: @Dirk The next() call on the generator stops when a match is found, therefore it does not have to traverse the entire list.

Comment: @aeter You make a fair point. I was referring to being able to stop when a match is found.

Comment: @Brent Newey: Assuming that you have to search half of the list on average to find the item you are looking for (some elements may be at the front of the list, others at the back) this gives you an expected run-time complexity of O(1/2n) = O(n) with a particular worst-case of always having to traverse the entire list, if the element is not present. Depends on your data, whether this is a frequent case. Stopping early does not change that.

Comment: Dict of dicts solved a similar issue for me in a very nice way +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

Seems most logical to use a filter/index combo:

```
names=[{}, {'name': 'Tom'},{'name': 'Tony'}]
names.index(next(filter(lambda n: n.get('name') == 'Tom', names)))
1
```

And if you think there could be multiple matches:

```
[names.index(item) for item in filter(lambda n: n.get('name') == 'Tom', names)]
[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer offered by @faham is a nice one-liner, but it doesn't return the index to the dictionary containing the value.  Instead it returns the dictionary itself.  Here is a simple way to get: A list of indexes one or more if there are more than one, or an empty list if there are none:

```
list = [{'id':'1234','name':'Jason'},
        {'id':'2345','name':'Tom'},
        {'id':'3456','name':'Art'}]

[i for i, d in enumerate(list) if 'Tom' in d.values()]
```

Output:

```
>>> [1]
```

What I like about this approach is that with a simple edit you can get a list of both the indexes and the dictionaries as tuples.  This is the problem I needed to solve and found these answers.  In the following, I added a duplicate value in a different dictionary to show how it works:

```
list = [{'id':'1234','name':'Jason'},
        {'id':'2345','name':'Tom'},
        {'id':'3456','name':'Art'},
        {'id':'4567','name':'Tom'}]

[(i, d) for i, d in enumerate(list) if 'Tom' in d.values()]
```

Output:

```
>>> [(1, {'id': '2345', 'name': 'Tom'}), (3, {'id': '4567', 'name': 'Tom'})]
```

This solution finds all dictionaries containing 'Tom' in any of their values.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that finds the dictionary's index position if it exists.

```
dicts = [{'id':'1234','name':'Jason'},
         {'id':'2345','name':'Tom'},
         {'id':'3456','name':'Art'}]

def find_index(dicts, key, value):
    class Null: pass
    for i, d in enumerate(dicts):
        if d.get(key, Null) == value:
            return i
    else:
        raise ValueError('no dict with the key and value combination found')

print find_index(dicts, 'name', 'Tom')
# 1
find_index(dicts, 'name', 'Ensnare')
# ValueError: no dict with the key and value combination found
```

Answer (score 2):

One liner!?

```
elm = ([i for i in mylist if i['name'] == 'Tom'] or [None])[0]
```

Comment: Doesn't return the index though.

Answer (score 0):

For a given iterable, [`more_itertools.locate`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.locate) yields positions of items that satisfy a predicate.

```
import more_itertools as mit


iterable = [
    {"id": "1234", "name": "Jason"},
    {"id": "2345", "name": "Tom"},
    {"id": "3456", "name": "Art"}
]

list(mit.locate(iterable, pred=lambda d: d["name"] == "Tom"))
# [1]
```

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third-party library that implements [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) among other useful tools.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a more general solution to account for the possibility of multiple dictionaries in the list having the key value, and a straightforward implementation using list comprehension:

```
dict_indices = [i for i, d in enumerate(dict_list) if d[dict_key] == key_value]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will return the index for the first matching item:

```
['Tom' == i['name'] for i in list].index(True)
```

Comment: It should have been `'Tom' == i['name']`

Comment: He fixed it, it works and I like it.  

Answer (score -1):

```
def search(itemID,list):
     return[i for i in list if i.itemID==itemID]
```

Answer (score -1):

my answer is better in one a dictionary to use

```py
food_time_dict = {"Lina": 312400, "Tom": 360054, "Den": 245800}
print(list(food_time_dict.keys()).index("Lina"))
```

I request keys from the dictionary, then I translate the list if it is not added, there will be an error then I use it as a list. but on your code:

```py
lists = [{'id': '1234', 'name': 'Jason'},
         {'id': '2345', 'name': 'Tom'},
         {'id': '3456', 'name': 'Art'}]
    
    
def dict_in_lists_index(lists, search):  # function for convenience
    j = 0  # [j][i]
    for i in lists:
        try:  # try our varible search if not found in list
            return f"[{j}][{list(i.values()).index(search)}]"
            # small decor
        except ValueError: # error was ValueError
            pass # aa... what must was what you want to do
        j += 1 # not found? ok j++
    return "Not Found"
    
    
def dict_cropped_index(lists, search):
    for i in lists:
        try:
            return list(i.values()).index(search)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return "Not Found"
    
    
print(dict_in_lists_index(lists, 'Tom')) # and end
print(dict_cropped_index(lists, 'Tom')) # now for sure end
```