# Python check if value is in a list of dicts

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts e.g.

```
[{'name':'Bernard','age':7},{'name':'George','age':4},{'name':'Reginald','age':6}]
```

I'd like to check to see if a string value is the same as the 'name' value in any of the dicts in the list. For example 'Harold' would be False, but 'George' would be True.

I realise I could do this by looping through each item in the list, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way?

Comment: even a build-in function would loop over the dict

Comment: Why are you representing your data this way? Why don't you create a class `Person` with the attributes `name` and `age`, and then create a list or dict of those?

Comment: if not duplicated, very related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391697/find-the-index-of-a-dict-within-a-list-by-matching-the-dicts-value

Comment: You could use `Person = collections.namedtuple('Person', 'name age')` instead of a dict as @Space_C0wb0y suggested: `L = [Person(**d) for d in L]` if individual items are readonly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there cannot be a more efficient way if you have just this list of dicts.

However, if you want to check frequently, you can extract a dictionary with name:age items:

```
l = [{'name':'Bernard','age':7},{'name':'George','age':4},{'name':'Reginald','age':6}]
d = dict((i['name'], i['age']) for i in l)
```

now you have `d`:

```
{'Bernard': 7, 'George': 4, 'Reginald': 6}
```

and now you can check:

```
'Harold' in d   -> False
'George' in d   -> True
```

It will be much faster than iterating over the original list.

Comment: Or better yet, extract it into a set. `s = set((i['name'] for i in l))`. +1

Comment: For the minute I don't need it multiple times, but I will definitely keep this in mind for the future, thanks.

Comment: Note: there *is* a more efficient way if you have just a list of dicts e.g., you could sort it `L.sort(key=itemgetter('name'))` and use `bisect` module to perform a binary search. In practice you would use a set as @Chinmay Kanchi suggested or a linear search with `any()` as in @KennyTM's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041981/python-check-if-value-is-in-a-list-of-dicts/6042003#6042003

Answer (score 15):

### The Proper Solution

There is a much more efficient way to do this than with looping. If you use `operators.itemgetter` you can do a simple `if x in y check`

```
#to simply check if the list of dicts contains the key=>value pair
'George' in map(itemgetter('name'), list_of_dicts)

#if you want to get the index 
index = map(itemgetter('name'), list_of_dicts).index("George") if 'George' in map(itemgetter('name'), list_of_dicts) else None
```

Comment: Or if you're using Python 3: `list(map(itemgetter('name'), list_of_dicts)).index('George')`. Can also put it inside a `try.. except ValueError` in case there is no item found with `list.index()`, rather than doing two `itemgetter()` lookups.

Answer (score 1):

I think a list comprehension would do the trick here too.

```
names = [i['name'] for i in l]
```

Then use it like so:

```
'Bernard' in names (True)
'Farkle' in names (False)
```

Or a one liner (If it's only one check)

```
'Bernard' in [i['name'] for i in l] (True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [{'name':'Bernard','age':7},{'name':'George','age':4},{'name':'Reginald','age':6}]
search_for = 'George'
print True in map(lambda person: True if person['name'].lower() == search_for.lower() else False, l )
```

Comment: This is not a very nice solution. KennyTM suggested a much simpler one using `any`, but for some reason he chose to delete it.

Comment: @BjörnPollex can you reproduce the answer here?

Answer (score 0):

```
smf = [{'name':'Bernard','age':7},{'name':'George','age':4},{'name':'Reginald','age':6}]
def names(d):
    for i in d:
        for key, value in i.iteritems():
             if key == 'name':
                 yield value


In [5]: 'Bernard' in names(smf)
Out[5]: True


In [6]: 'Bernardadf' in names(smf)
Out[6]: False
```