# Verified dictionaries value with the same key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this :

```
[{'Name': 'Andri', 'Age': '20'}, {'Name': 'Nova', 'Age':'24'}]
```

Now my question is how can I verify if `Nova` is a member of the dictionaries or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if value already exists within list of dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897499/check-if-value-already-exists-within-list-of-dictionaries) OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041981/python-check-if-value-is-in-a-list-of-dicts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how i can verified if Nova is a member of the dictionaries or no

This to me sounds like you just want a `True` or `False` if `'Nova'` exists.

You can use `any()` to check if `'Nova'` exists in the `'Name'` key:

```
>>> d = [{'Name': 'Andri', 'Age': 20}, {'Name': 'Nova', 'Age': 24}]
>>> any(x['Name'] == 'Nova' for x in d)
True
```

Or you can check the `values()` specifically:

```
>>> any(v == 'Nova' for x in d for v in x.values())
True
```

Or using the `in` operator:

```
>>> any('Nova' in x.values() for x in d)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_filter.asp) function.

```
In [10]: l
Out[10]: [{'Name': 'Andri', 'Age': 20}, {'Name': 'Nova', 'Age': '24'}]

In [11]: r=filter(lambda x: 'Nova' in x.values(),l)

In [12]: list(r)
Out[12]: [{'Name': 'Nova', 'Age': '24'}]
```

Answer (score -2):

if 'Nova' in #dictionaryName.itervalues():

Comment: To name just one problem with this, `itervalues` is only available in [tag:python-2.x] and this question is tagged [tag:python-3.x]