# List indices must be integers, not dict

Tags: python

I'm making a script for the game and i need help about grabbing dictionary information out of json.

[image: JSON]

So far I've dealt with list and I didn't had problem grabbing that information.

```
req['result']['trades'][key]['output']
```

This is my try of grabbing the info after which i get error list indices must be integers, not dict.

Any help greatly appreciated.

json print, i have removed some account sensitive data.

```
{
    'fue_step': 30,
    'type': 'm',
    'rubies': xxx, 
    'might': xxx,
    'race': 'xxx',
    'result': {
        'trades': [
            {
                'id': 13,
                'requirement': ['VenomTrapPart', 1],
                'token_cost': 1,
                'output': ['VulcansBlessingRare', 1],
                'name': 'VenomVulcan',
                'enabled': True
            }, 
            {
                'id': 14,
                'requirement': ['EternalRune', 50],
                'token_cost': 1,
                'output': ['ColossalMite500TroopPrizeItem', 1],
                'name': 'EternalColossal',
                'enabled': True
            }, 
            {
                'id': 86,
                'requirement':['RenameProclamation', 25],
                'token_cost': 1,
                'output': ['TimeTrickstersBag', 1],
                'name': 'RenameTrick',
                'enabled': True
            },
            {
                'id': 95,
                'requirement': ['FireDragonBlaze', 1],
                'token_cost': 1,
                'output': ['FireTroop1000TroopPrizeItem', 10],
                'name': 'BlazeFireTroop',
                'enabled': True
            },
            {
                'id': 100,
                'requirement': ['StoneDragonQuake', 1],
                'token_cost': 1,
                'output': ['StoneTroop10kTroopPrizeItem', 1],
                'name': 'StoneDQStoneTroop',
                'enabled': True
            },
            {
                'id': 113,
                'requirement': ['VulcansBlessing15Elite', 3],
                'token_cost': 1,
                'output': ['VulcansBlessing16Elite', 1],
                'name': '15 --> 16 Elite',
                'enabled': True
            },
            {
                'id': 114,
                'requirement': ['LunaPowder', 25],
                'token_cost': 1,
                'output': ['IceTroop50kTroopPrizeItem', 1],
                'name': 'Luna Powder --> Soul Reapers',
                'enabled': True
            },
            {
                'id': 115,
                'requirement': ['GreaterCrystalDefense', 5],
                'token_cost': 1,
                'output': ['MasterCrystalDefense', 1],
                'name': 'Greater Defense --> Master Defense',
                'enabled': True
            },
            {
                'id': 116,
                'requirement': ['NanoCanisters', 3],
                'token_cost': 1,
                'output': ['TestroniusDeluxe', 1],
                'name': 'Nano Canisters for Deluxes',
                'enabled': True
            },
            {
                'id': 117,
                'requirement': ['VulcansBlessing16Common', 3],
                'token_cost': 1,
                'output': ['VulcansBlessing17Common', 1],
                'name': "Common +16's for Common +17",
                'enabled': True
            }
        ], 
        'trades_today': 0,
        'doubloons_left': 9567,
        'free_trades_left': 1,
        'success': True,
        'auto_confirm': True,
        'trade_reset_date':1450771200
    },
    'client_cachebreaker': '1449879464'
```

Comment: There are 4 things we need to know the data-structure of first:

Comment: ['result']['trades'][key]['output'] each individually.

Comment: The hierarchy in the image you posted is difficult to understand. Can you `print` the JSON instead and post that?

Comment: Have you tried `d = json.loads(input_string)` (or `json.load` if reading form a file directly)

Comment: If the error message tells you that the interpreter thinks you have a `list` there, then that's what you have.

Comment: @Jason 
I have done json.loads and it successfully loads json file.
It is in form of a dictionary and that's what makes it the problem for me. So far i have only worked with lists and grabbing information from them was easy. 

1st item under output is item and 2nd is value(amount), the thing i need to do is somehow call them and use further in script. 

I will post json in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your edit to include indentation in your `JSON` so that it is more readable. As soon as the edit is approved, you'll be able to see it.

Here is an example of how to access a value deep within the object:

```
print req['result']['trades'][4]['name']
```

**Output:**

```
StoneDQStoneTroop
```

If you want to access dicts within a list by their values, [here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391697/find-the-index-of-a-dict-within-a-list-by-matching-the-dicts-value) that explains a few ways to do so. This would allow you, for example, to find a dict in `req['result']['trades']` by its `'id'` value instead of by its index within the `'trades'` list.

Comment: Thank you, i will read it. Values like name, token cost, id i know how to get. Dict is a problem so thanks a lot for your help.