# Replacing a specific item of a dict in a list of dicts?

Tags: python

Say I have the following list of dicts:

```py
dicts = [
    {'name': "Tom", 'age': 20, 'height': 1.8},
    {'name': "Isa", 'age': 31, 'height': 1.5},
    ... ]
```

I'd like to replace the age of a given person with a given value.

```py
def replace_age(person, age):
    dicts[?]['age'] = age

replace_age("Tom", 45)
```

Assuming that `name` is unique, what's the most elegant way to go about this?

---

In a golden world: `dicts[name=person]['age'] = age`

---

Not a duplicate of [Find the index of a dict within a list, by matching the dict's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391697/find-the-index-of-a-dict-within-a-list-by-matching-the-dicts-value): I'm looking to change the value, not get the index. And Tom is a pretty common name.

Comment: I want to change the value, not get the index.

Comment: You first have to identify the proper dict in your list if you want to update it, that's the same as finding it's index. Also, your last remark 'Tom is a pretty common name' makes me wonder what you would want to do if there are many Toms in your list. That makes your question unclear...

Comment: @snazzybouche it's the critical part of your question. changing the value for a particular dictionary key is trivial and part of the Python language. Finding the right dictionary is covered by the duplicated question. I like code golf as much as the next person but it's not going to help you any more than the dupe will (though I admit I am always fond of the crazy one-liners people come up with)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille For the purposes of this question I have asserted that `name` is unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a variant:

```
def replace_age(person, age):
    try:
        dct = next(item for item in dicts if item["name"] == person)
    except StopIteration:
        # person not found
        # here you could print a message or raise an error...
        return
    dct["age"] = age
```

this will only work if the names are unique. if they are not only the first occurrence will be replaced.

Comment: the dictionary is changed in-place. for these functions it is conventional to return None. i have no idea what the OP needs if the person is not found in the dict...

Comment: I agree with hiro, it's better to pass None as second argument in next function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version

```
dictionaries = [
    {'name': "Tom", 'age': 20, 'height': 1.8},
    {'name': "Isa", 'age': 31, 'height': 1.5}
    ]

def change_dict_person_age(dictionaries, person, age):
    for dictionary in dictionaries:
        if dictionary['name'] == person:
            dictionary['age'] = age
            # Uncomment the following line if you want to stop at the 1st
            # match. Leave it as is if you want to modify all occurrences.
            #break

change_dict_person_age(dictionaries, "Tom", 40)
print(dictionaries)
#[{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 40, 'height': 1.8}, {'name': 'Isa', 'age': 31, 'height': 1.5}]
```

I also wrote a more generic version for broader user:

```
dictionaries = [
    {'name': "Tom", 'age': 20, 'height': 1.8},
    {'name': "Isa", 'age': 31, 'height': 1.5}
    ]

def change_dict(dictionaries, key_to_check, value_to_match, key_to_change, value_to_change):
    for dictionary in dictionaries:
        if dictionary[key_to_check] == value_to_match:
            dictionary[key_to_change] = value_to_change
            # Uncomment the following line if you want to stop at the 1st
            # match. Leave it as is if you want to modify all occurrences.
            #break

change_dict(dictionaries, "name", "Tom", "age", 50)
print(dictionaries)
#[{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 50, 'height': 1.8}, {'name': 'Isa', 'age': 31, 'height': 1.5}]
```

Comment: Your broader use is the perfect use case for kwargs

Comment: Good point @snazzybouche but then how could I have more fine grained control about which is the value to check and which is the one to change? Just positional?

Comment: Mmm, good counterpoint. I don't believe kwargs are ordered so you're right, that wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

since the `name` is unique you can change your data structure where you keep your data to achieve your task efficiently:

```
efficient_dict = {e['name']: {'age' : e.get('age'), 'height': e.get('height')} for e in dicts}

def replace_age(person, age):
    if person in efficient_dict:
        efficient_dict[person]['age'] = age
```