# How to delete a dictionary in a list in python?

Tags: python

I am just looking for help to delete a specific dictionary in a list with a specific stipulation without using the index number.

For example, how would I remove supplier  with `supplier_id=103` in the following

```
suppliers = [
{"contact_firstname": "Jason", 
 "supplier_id": 101},
{"contact_firstname": "Paul", 
 "supplier_id": 102},
{"contact_firstname": "Mark", 
 "supplier_id": 103}]
```

Comment: Get the index of the element you want to remove, then use `suppliers.pop(index)`

Comment: I'm trying to do it without knowing the index number. I understand you can use this but was looking a way to do it without

Comment: You can find the index number with a simple loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391697/find-the-index-of-a-dict-within-a-list-by-matching-the-dicts-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
suppliers[:] = [d for d in suppliers if d.get('supplier_id') != 103]
```

Comment: Can you try to understand/explain why this answer worked and mine didn't?

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this:

```
supplier_list2 = [x for x in suppliers if x["supplier_id"] != 103]
```

It will remove all entries with supplier_id 103. If you want to exclude a list of ID's:

```
excluded = [102, 103]
supplier_list2 = [x for x in suppliers if x["supplier_id"] not in excluded]
```

Comment: I copied and pasted that directly and then proceeded to reprint the list and it came out exactly the same. Not sure what's wrong

Comment: @JakeLazzari Did you print `suppliers` or `supplier_list2`?